# Is History the right site to ask why success in war seems to be usually measured in recent gains in area and not damage to the enemy fighting ability?

Tags: support, site-policy

I was watching a video giving analysis of the the war in Ukraine. This is the link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DNh0heEi1EY. Not for the first time, I found myself wondering why the focus of the analysis is on the amount of territory controlled, rather than the amount of fight, so to speak, that each nation possesses. The analyst said Ukraine now controls ninety something percent of Kharkiv Oblast. How does that help Ukraine in the longterm, I wondered. That area of ground doesn't contain weapons, soldiers, or any other thing that can be used against the Russians, does it? Surely what determines the outcome is how much military material each side loses or gains, and not territory. In chess, gains are usually gains of material, while the total number of squares controlled is never mentioned. Why is it so different in war?
I Googled the question and could find only stuff about how things related to territory *cause* war, but nothing about why territory is *useful* in winning a war. I couldn't find a military strategy SE site. I see that military strategy is discussed on History, and also on Politics, and in computer game and simulation related sites here, too. History seemed to be the most promising, though.

................................................................................

I guess another way of putting the question would be, "Does pushing the enemy back a few kilometers cause the enemy to be more likely to lose the war or does it merely indicate it?" Generals seem to focus on pushing back the enemy, or at least they and everyone else regard as it as a success and I don't see why. "Pushing back" is of course figurative, and it really means causing the enemy to choose to retreat. Napoleon, and Hitler both pushed back the enemy a lot, but the *way* they pushed the enemy back caused them to lose the war, in each case, or rather, the way the enemy retreated (scorched earth) did, am I right?

One person who posted an answer suspected that I might be here to have argument. While not averse to spirited debate, it wasn't my conscious intention to have an argument here. Also, I don't consider myself knowledgeable about history or military strategy. I am genuinely mystified about the role of "pushing back" the enemy in getting to a final victory. It seems to me that it might be a symptom of progress towards victory rather than a cause of it. To make the enemy retreat you have to damage the enemy's ability to make war, and it's the latter that makes a final victory more likely, not the actual possession of that territory, perhaps?

Answer (score 5):

Not likely.

The question would work, perhaps, for a specific war, though even there it would be hard to settle.  But if you asked it in general, there would be too many questions about evidence or even whether it has the same answer in all cases.

Comment: Is there another SE site where the question would work?

Answer (score 3):

I think such a question *could* work here, but it would be tricky. The big problems I see with it are:

1. Historiography - Questions about the study of history itself are on topic here, but they tend to be on thin ice. It needs to be pretty clear this is a historiography question, and otherwise a good History question, which makes any further problems it has more serious.
2. Unsupported assertions - We have a really bad time here with people making all kinds of outlandish assertions and then asking us to somehow base answers on that shaky foundation. Any non-trivial assertions in a question need to be supported. For instance, having a specific link and analysis the question is referring to that we are free to go look at ourselves is great! Asserting that this is the normal/usual way people analyze things with only the one exemplar is not so great.
3. Unclear question. I'm still not 100% sure what the question would be here. It almost looks like you're looking to argue with the author, or perhaps one of our writers foolishly taking up the author's case, rather than asking a question you'd seriously desire to know the answer to. Our users who answer questions are generally here because they enjoy writing about history to a receptive audience. So if there's a specific question about history you'd like to know the answer to, the text of the *question* should be explaining clearly what that question is. If you're instead looking for an argument, [you want 12A next door](https://www.virginiawestern.edu/eng111/ArgumentClinic-MontyPython.pdf).